# Manipulating the output of variables in Django with JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I use this piece of code to grab part of the description from video object:

```
        <div id="description">
            <p>{{video.description | slice:":20" }}</p>
            <button onclick="showDescription()">Show description</button>
        </div>
```

There I got `showDescription()` function, I want it to display the rest of the description by changing the inner HTML code:

```
function showDescription() {
    var text = document.getElementById('description')
    text.innerHTML = "<p style='overflow-wrap: break-word; width: 100%;'>{{video.description}}</p>"
};
```

But it returns

```
{{video.description}}
```

Instead of actual description, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `{{video.description}}` as a function argument.

```
<div id="description">
    <p>{{video.description | slice:":20" }}</p>
    <button onclick="showDescription('{{video.description}}')">Show description</button>
</div>

function showDescription(description) {
    var text = document.getElementById('description')
    text.innerHTML = "<p style='overflow-wrap: break-word; width: 100%;'>" + description + "</p>"
};
```